# refer variable from controller to all blade Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I've code in my controller which returns some `$data`, and I want to refer that in all my blades, I can make routes for each page, but I don't like this way. I thought should be better if I refer this `$data` on `layout.blade` which include navbar, and etc..., but is it a possible to make route without url? cause I don't want to appear my `layout.blade`, So my question is, what is a best way to get `$data` on each blade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may perhaps want a view composer.  A view composer is an extension of a blade via php that runs before the blade.

In app service provider you set the view you want to view composer class.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use App\Http\ViewComposers\LayoutComposer;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
     public function boot()
     {
          View::composer('layout', LayoutComposer::class);
     }
 }
```

Then write your logic in the class.

```
use Illuminate\View\View;

class LayoutComposer
{
    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $data = Model::where('id',###)->first();

        return $view->with(['data' => $data]);
    }

}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/views#view-composers

Comment: Thank you that works perfectly! but is it a necessary to my function name was `compose`?, cause when I changing function name, it's get me back error. am I able to manually define my function name?

Comment: Looks like what is going on here is that the framework iterates through each Composer class found in the app service provider, and sets the function called "compose" to a callback.  That callback is then attached to an event that executes when the view loads. https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/View/Concerns/ManagesEvents.php#L40. Calling the function anything different will cause an error because the framework expects there to be a function called "compose" in that class.